# Running SAS Procedures from Command Line

Tags: shell, unix, sas

I have a few scripts which I use to run simple SAS commands from the command line that I'm working on updating. One that I'm having an issue with is `proc freq`. It works fine as it's written now, but I'd like to be able to change the format of the output.

Here is the working code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "libname home ''; proc freq data=home.$1; tables $2/ missing list;" > user$USER.sas 
nohup sas -memsize 0m -sortsize -0m -autoexec /users/me/sastools/autoexec.sas user$USER.sas
more user$USER.lst
```

Now, I've made a few changes that allow me to change the output format.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "libname home ''; proc freq data=home.$1; tables $2/ missing out=t outcum noprint; run;
proc print data=t(drop=percent cum_pct) noobs; format count cum_freq comma15.; run;" > user$USER.sas
nohup sas -memsize 0m -sortsize -0m -autoexec /users/me/sastools/autoexec.sas user$USER.sas
more user$USER.lst
```

The new code works if I only specify one variable in the `tables` statement, but this is a rare occurrence. When I try to add multiple variables it will only return the first.

Here are a few examples of how this is run:

```
fr dataset var1*var2
fr 'dataset; where var1 = condition; weight var2;' var4*var5
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is `outcum` option. Even with `list` specified, `outcum` only works for one-way tables. The way to circumvent the problem is to add a data step to calculate any cumulative statistics.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "libname home ''; proc freq data=home.$1; tables $2/ missing out=t noprint; run;
data t; set t(drop=percent); Cum_Freq + Count; run;
proc print data=t noobs; format count cum_freq comma15.; run;" > user$USER.sas
nohup sas -memsize 0m -sortsize -0m -autoexec /users/me/sastools autoexec.sas user$USER.sas
more user$USER.lst
```

I hope this helps anyone with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `*` is being expanded or otherwise treated as something other than the `*` character.  Try quoting the argument perhaps, when you pass it to avoid this issue.

```
fr dataset "var1*var2"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the problem was actually the `outcum` option. I wasn't aware that the argument wouldn't work for n-way (n > 1) tables. I just had to recreate `Cum_Freq` in a data step.

Comment: You might want to use the `-stdio` command line option. This would eliminate the need to create a physical SAS program file. Plus it will allow your lines of SAS code in your script to look more normal instead of having to be wrapped inside of ECHO command(s).

Comment: @Tom How would you suggest using `-stdio`? When I use that option from the command line it's usually in this format:  `echo "SAS Code" | sas -stdio`.

Comment: You can redirect the command file contents to std input something like: `sas -stdio << ENDSASCODE | proc print data=sashelp.class; | run;| ENDSASCODE|` You can use any unique string you want in place of `ENDSASCODE`.